# Order by title - but now built in wordpress func, sort the_title

Tags: query, order, plugin-qtranslate, wp-title

I've got a pretty simple WP installation, where I use qtranslate plugin to keep site in two languages.
The problem is, I need to sort posts by title, and as probably you know (as you use qtranslate), that causes the problem - it sorts posts by mysql entries (which are two because of languages), and that gives me unwanted order (from the first language).

What I want to do, is get the first letter of evert post and sort it by this, in php, do you think it is good solution? If so, how to do this best way?

```
<?php query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'publishers', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of `query_posts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it would be very hard to do. qTranslate stores all titles in one database field as concatenated string with some additional markup, so there is no chance to sort them using SQL and to do it fast.

You can do one of 2 things:

**1. Stop using qTranslate**

It really has many other flaws. You can use WPML or Polylang instead - both are much better.

**2. Sort them in PHP**

Don't sort posts in query with SQL and sort them with PHP after running this query. `WP_Query` stores found posts in `$wp_query->posts`. You can sort this array with PHP. Of course you will have to select all posts to make it work, so if there are many posts in this query, it's rather bad idea. But if there are only few of them, then it shouldn't be so bad...

Sample code below - written in here, so may be buggy.

```
<?php
    $my_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'page', 'orderby'=>'title', 'order'=>'ASC', 'posts_per_page'=>-1) );
    if ( $my_query ->have_posts() ):
?>
<ul class="posts-list">
    <?php
        $found_posts = array();
        foreach ( $my_query->posts as $k=>$p ) {
            $found_posts[ apply_filters('the_title', $p->post_title) ] = $p;
        }
        ksort($found_posts);
        $i=0;
        foreach ($found_posts as $k=>$p) {
            $my_query->posts[$i++] = $p;
        }
    ?>
    <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ): $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I see we are both from Poland :).
So Polylang can do this? I've got about 20 posts… And was wondering to do this even by js, by php seems better

Comment: Polylang (like WPML) stores every version of post as separate post, so you can sort them easily. If you can change plugin now, I would change it ASAP. If you can't (site is big and it would be time-consuming) you can always try to sort them in PHP.

Comment: Could you post me some example how to sort inside query in php? It will be very helpfull

Comment: Just to add my 2 off-topic cents, I've found WPML much more confusing for admins, much more cluttered, buggier and and much more prone to deleting translations by mistake. Qtranslate is clunky/hacky, but works and is much more usable for most use cases.